# Counting floor tiles in a video, and making sure to have the total number at the end?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video, counting, tiles

The question is basically asking to calculate the total number of floor tiles from a 10second video for example. Assumptions: the tiles are all rectangular. If the video is 10seconds and it has 30fps, that is around 300 images. There are 2 problems here
1- To detect the floor tile in 1 image
2- The second frame, will have the same floor tile from the first frame, we don't want to keep adding the same floor tiles again and again. Any idea of how to solve each part, I am new to image processing?

Image is shared as an example only, I have 10second video as explained earlier, these tiles can be found in bathroom or kitchen

[image: kitchen tiles for demo only]

Comment: Show us typical images.

Comment: I added the image, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

With proper image binarization followed by erosion/dilation, you should be able to isolate the individual tiles. Below, size reduction + adaptive thresholding + erosion. You can complete with hole filling to recover entire tiles, then connected components.

Now for covering the whole floor, as all tiles are identical, it is *crucial* that you work by tracking: detect the tiles in all frames and limit the motion speed in such a way that the displacement is smaller than one tile between two frames. This way, by overlapping, you can follow them individually and gradually build a "tile map" for the whole room.

[image]